# How to turn filenames with line numbers into hyperlinks?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am novice emacs user, and currently i am trying to set up work environment for python. I am using rope, but has come across the following: although rope's "Find occurences" command works fine, its result are put in a modeless buffer, and to access them i must copy file names.

Buffer contents are [here](http://pastebin.com/rf1Dq9wR)

As far as i can tell, closes functionality to what i want (that is, opening a file on a given line after clicking on it or pressing RET) is provided by compilation-mode. However, as things are, enabling compilation-mode only causes highlighting of the filenames.

If i undestand correctly, to process lines i need to provide items into compilation-error-regexp-alist, like it is done in following snippet (from [emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompilationMode)

```
(require 'compile)

(let ((symbol  'compilation-ledger)
      (pattern '("^Error: \"\\([^\"\n]+?\\)\", line \\([0-9]+\\):" 1 2)))
  (cond ((eval-when-compile (boundp 'compilation-error-regexp-systems-list))
         ;; xemacs21
         (add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist
                      (list symbol pattern))
         (compilation-build-compilation-error-regexp-alist))
        ((eval-when-compile (boundp 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist))
         ;; emacs22 up
         (add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist symbol)
         (add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist
                      (cons symbol pattern)))
        (t
         ;; emacs21
         (add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist pattern))))
```

How should i modify it to make it work with my buffer?

Are there better/quicker alternatives?

Comment: `find-file-at-point` will probably give you the functionality you want.  I don't use python, but are you sure that `rope` puts things in a modeless buffer?  Go to that buffer and check with `M-: major-mode` -- once you've got that, you can bind a key to `find-file-at-point` in that mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, the quickest way to open a file when its name is displayed in a buffer is

```
M-x ffap
```

(short for `M-x find-file-at-point`)

If you want to open the file automatically, you could define your own function:

```
(defun open-file-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((file (ffap-file-at-point)))
    (if file
        (find-file file)
      (error "No file at point"))))
```

and maybe bind it to a key with

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<return>") 'open-file-at-point)
```

If you want to use `compilation-mode`, you will have to add a matching regexp to `compilation-error-regexp-alist(-alist)`. For your example, the following seems to work:

```
(add-to-list
 'compilation-error-regexp-alist
 'python-file-name)

(add-to-list
 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist
 (list
  'python-file-name
  (concat "\\(?1:.*?\\)"              ;; file name
          " : "                       ;; seperator
          "\\(?2:[[:digit:]]+\\)")    ;; line number
   1 2)) ;; subexpr 1 is the file name, subexp 2 is the line number
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved all the problems i was having in this particular case.
While `ffap` us useful, (and i did not know about it before), visiting file on a given line that compilation-mode now can do for my buffer is even more so. No more M-g g for that )))